# Bootstrap "jumbotron-narrow" example. how does the style change?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm going over the bootstrap site example http://getbootstrap.com/examples/jumbotron-narrow/#
and when I hover my mouse over the "About" or "Contact" links a grey rounded box appears around the text. When the mouse leaves the element, the grey rounded box disappears.

This is driving me crazy! I have inspected these elements and gone through the styles applied to them and have gone through every single one of them, all the inherited ones, the whole lot. Can someone go through the css and tell me exactly how this is happening? I expected to find some sort of :hover or :focus css but none exists. Furthermore it is not javascript that is changing the background as I have tested the site with javascript enabled.

Please help and I will love you forever.

Comment: bootstrap rarely uses js for styling, it's all css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you are looking for:

```
.nav > li > a:hover, .nav > li > a:focus {
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #EEE;
}
```

[image]

### Super simple, fix:

```
<link bootstrap />
<link custom />  <-- Overwrite CSS by placing external file after in HTML
```

### Or:

```
<link bootstrap />
<style></style> <-- Overwrites bootstrap's external CSS
```

### CSS to change is simple:

```
.nav > li > a:hover, .nav > li > a:focus {
    background-color: none;
}
```

### Why does Bootstrap make it so if you hover, it turns grey?

It is because it tells the visitors, that they are on something clickable: a link. And making it more user-friendly and improves a website's UX.

Answer (score 0):

There are an CSS applied when you hovered these elements -

```
.nav>li>a:hover, .nav>li>a:focus {
   text-decoration: none;
   background-color: #eee;
}
```

Please see highlighted in red - 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/GH6y8/1/)</kbd>

html

```
<ul class="nav">
    <li> <a href="#">About</a>

    </li>
</ul>
```

css

```
   .nav>li>a:hover, .nav>li>a:focus {
        text-decoration: none;
        background-color: #eee;
    }
    .nav>li>a {
        position: relative;
        display: block;
        padding: 10px 15px;
        border-radius: 4px;
        text-decoration:none;
        width:50px;
        text-align:center;
    }
    .nav {
        list-style: none;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The buttons background turns grey because of the following css in the bootstrap.min.css file:

```
nav>li>a:hover,.nav>li>a:focus{text-decoration:none;background-color:#eee}
```

You can run a find on the code mentioned before to find it in the bootstrap.min.css file.